# React: React 17 -> React 18, странное предупреждение

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Вылезает предупреждение:

> Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use
> createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will
> behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more:
> https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

хотя вроде как всё что требуется я сделал (например index.ts):

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

подскажите откуда вылезает ворринг, вроде все сделал, что требуется, или надо где-то еще правки сделать?

P.S.

похоже это как-то связано с использованием метода `componentDidMount`

Comment: Где у вас используется `ReactDOM.render`?

Comment: @Randall, не понял. Есть `root.render`, а `root` - результат того, что выдает `createRoot`, а во всех компонентах обычный метод `render`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такую запись. У меня с ней проблем не возникало.

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);


import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

Comment: то же самое, да и `import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'` вроде как по сути из `ReactDOM` и вытаскивает `createRoot `

Comment: Может ему не хватает свойства tab? Как в документации (см.ответ)

Comment: похоже что-то не очень очевидное у меня - сделал так что App никакие другие компоненты не выводит и ворнинг исчез значит надо копать пока не найду что за компонент и уже смотреть в него :(

Comment: похоже это как-то связано с использованием метода `componentDidMount`